# Git command to open all files in a commit?

Tags: git, commit

I know you can list all files in a commit using:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r bd61ad98
```

But is there a command that can open all files in a commit in an editor of choice, such a sublime?

Answer (score 5):

You could just do this from the shell, using backticks to send the output of the command to the editor's command:

```
$ vi `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r bd61ad98`
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use a more 'porcelain' (*) command like `git show`.

```
$ emacs $(git show --name-only --format=  bd61ad98)
```

Backticks as in @Mureinik's response, as opposed to `$()`,  work just fine too.

(*) Git has an informal concept of 'plumbing' and 'porcelain': 'porcelain' commands are more user-centric. 'plumbing' commands like `diff-tree` are more aimed at the sysadmin or perhaps power user.